# Hibernate Named Query Using Like and % % operators?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

In my Hibernate JPA Sample code..

```
public List<AttendeesVO> addAttendees(String searchKeyword) {
    TypedQuery<AttendeesVO> query = entityManager.createQuery(" select at from AttendeesVO at where at.user.firstName LIKE :searchKeyword",AttendeesVO.class);
    query.setParameter("searchKeyword", searchKeyword+"%");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

it is working fine when giving entire String `firstName=Narasimham`

But it is not working when we give any character of `Narasimham` i.e `a` or `n`

Actually my thinking is i'm giving `Like` operator with `% %` so it working any character of given String..

Answer (score 61, accepted):

you are using `query.setParameter("searchKeyword", searchKeyword+"%");`

instead of `query.setParameter("searchKeyword", "%"+searchKeyword+"%");`

first one will return rows for `Narasimham` `N` `Na` `Nar` `Nara` etc.

Answer (score 19):

> But it is not working when we give any character of Narasimham i.e a
>   or n

Because you are doing case sensitive search. Try `N`, `Na`, `Nar` instead. If you want to perform a case insensitive search try using `upper` or `lower`. like

```
entityManager.createQuery("select at from AttendeesVO at where lower(at.user.firstName) LIKE lower(:searchKeyword)",AttendeesVO.class);
```

> Actually my thinking is i'm giving Like operator with % %

`searchKeyword+"%"` means return values which *starts with* searchKeyword.
`"%"+searchKeyword+"%"` means return values which *contains* searchKeyword.
Decide as per your requirment.

Answer (score 9):

I would add my voice to @ssk to use two % before and after the keyword.
Or I think its more professional solution if you configured it in the query itself like this :

```
public List<AttendeesVO> addAttendees(String searchKeyword) {
    TypedQuery<AttendeesVO> query = entityManager.createQuery(" select at from AttendeesVO 
    at where at.user.firstName LIKE CONCAT('%',:searchKeyword,'%')",AttendeesVO.class);
    query.setParameter("searchKeyword", searchKeyword);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

**because the '%' its part of the query** not of the parameter what you may fill it out later

> The CONCAT() function adds two or more expressions together.
>   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp